# Graph theory name/algorithm help required

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Apologies on the title, cant use 'Graph theory problem name'.

I'm trying to process some data, where I need to extract information on structures contained within the data.

- Is a volume of space enclosed
- Volume of said enclosed space

**Edit:**
The initial 'raw' data is in a series bytes, which I can access similar to a multidimensional array.

```
//   X   Y   Z 
data(10, 10, 8);   // 0
data(10, 10, 9);   // 1
data(10, 10, 10);  // 1 
data(10, 10, 11);  // 1
```

Each neighbor in this data structure would be a possible edge-node pair, if there is a value greater than zero in the data at that position. So each element/node in the data structure could have six possible edges.

Its trivial for me to transform this raw data into a graph like structure, since I know the starting position (seed).

```
node = dataToGraph(10,10,10); // seed position 
node->Edges[0]; // this would correspond to node represented by the value at 9,10,10
                // returns null if the value is less than zero. i.e. no edge/node.
```

The data represents structures in 3D space, and each structure will have a specific seed(in dark grey below) of which the position is known. From this position I need to scan the data/structure to verify its a complete structure,i.e. no gaps, and if it is, compute its internal volume.

While I'm sure I'd be able to kludge some sort of solution, its not going to be optimal, and there are millions of these structures to scan per data set.

I'm guessing there is a standard graph theory solution I could use which would be better than anything I would hack out. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with this sort of math, so I don't even know where to start looking.

Below are three examples, of a 2D slice of the data which would be valid. The red line on #3 illustrates the pruned structure I'm interested in for that example.

A valid structure always has the seed, the structure is fully closed. Invalid structures would be any structure which have a gap, anywhere in the complete 3D structure, or the seed had more than two neighbors/edges on the slice it exists on. i.e. it must not be blocked on the external or internal surface.

The new picture of the cube below illustrates this to a degree. Assume it has a hollow interior. The red sphere is the seed, the blue line represents a single slice, #1 in the 2D example. Unfortunately, its never going to be a structure as regular as this, hence the need for the graph algorithms imo.

I'd appreciate if someone could provide some pointers on where to start on this. I'm not expecting someone to feed me code, just to educate me ;)

[image: slice]
[image: cube]

Comment: Your spec is way too vague.  What form are the "data" in?  How do you decide that one is connected to another?  To apply graph theory, you must have a graph: vertices and edges.  How is a graph encoded in your data?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. I'll add more detail than this if required. I'm trying to keep the question as concise as possible, which was why I excluded that stuff initially.

Comment: I'm still confused.  You're showing 2d examples but say the problem is 3d.  Are you looking for a closed 2d polygon or a closed 3d volume?  What happens of the seed point is touching multiple polygons/volumes?  What if the seed point is on an edge inclusion of the polygon/volume (like the inner tip of the cross in a Q)?

Comment: @Gene: "Below are three examples, of a 2D **slice** of the data which would be valid." so it's one layer of the input. You can stack multiple layers to get a closed 3D volume problem. But I'm confused because he also said "Invalid structures would be any structure which had a gap, or the seed had more than two neighbors/edges.", which can't be possible in a 3D structure, as each point will have three to four neighbors. Need to wait for OP clarification.

Comment: Just updated there. Both of you raise good points. Thanks for the feedback.
@Gene I'm looking to confirm its a closed 3D volume. If it was in said inner tip, it wouldn't be a valid structure.

Comment: @justhalf Yea you're right, what I had there was incorrect. Updated, hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the blocks connected to a specific initial seed-block you use a depth-first search algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Then to calculate the volume?

Comment: @justhalf: add up the found cells?  Each cell is volume 1 right?

Comment: Volume I think should be the number of cells inside the structure, right? Depth first search is only the first step, to find the boundary of the structure.

Comment: @justhalf: Ok, the problem was unclear.  To find the volume inside the structure, find one cell inside the structure, then perform a DFS starting at that cell (with no edges between inner cells and boundary cells).  Then count the total inner cells.

Comment: I think it's better to use BFS for "flooding" the volume.

Comment: @justhalf: Why do you think BFS is better than DFS for this?  They should be both the same I think, O(volume) time and space.

Comment: I'm in the process of implementing this. A DFS to confirm a closed structure, and a BFS to flood/count the volume. Stay tuned...

Comment: @jasper: You shouldn't need both.  After the DFS you will just be able to count your done set.  Or each time you visit a cell increment a count.

Answer (score 0):

Following are steps that would solve your problem : -

1.> Construct a directed graph from the data points (Use DFS to construct directed graphs Starting from seeds as source).

2.> Compute Strongly Connected Components of Graph

3.> check which SCC the seed belong to and that will be your valid gaps

Time complexity will be T(E) no of edge in the graph.

Pseudo Code for above algorithm: -

```
for(int i = 0;i<seeds.length;i++) {

DiGraph = []
DFS(seeds[i],Digraph);
comps = SCC(Digraph)
getVolume(comps[seeds[i]])

}

//DFS for above algorithm

DFS(Node i,Digraph) {

if(!visited(i)) {
   visited(i) = true 

  for every adjacent node v {

       Digraph.AddEdge((i,v))
       DFS(v,Digraph)

  }

}
}


getVolume(component k) {

   // get all 8 points bounding the gap
   Bounds = getBounds(k);
   Count = floodFill(Bounds);
   return(Count)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the SCC part please? After reading about [SCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component), it looks like the SCC would only contain two vertices. The seed vertex, and the vertex next to the seed?

Comment: SCC is component of graph in which from each vertex we can reach any other vertex in the component and if you notice your graph if convert to directed graph using DFS then all vertices in a gap will fall in one SCC